How to make Cyrillic alphabet numbering in enumerate with enumitem and polyglossia
I found that there is \asbuk provided by polyglossia, but it doesn't work. This is my mwe:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands, forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{wide, nosep, font=\rmfamily\normalfont}
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=\asbuk*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Текст
    \item Еще текст
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

It produces just ).

You get several errors, which you shouldn't ignore.
See section 8.1 in the manual of enumitem.
I used \show\asbuk to find what the internal representation is.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands, forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}

\makeatletter
\AddEnumerateCounter{\asbuk}{\russian@asbuk@alph}{щ} % section 8.1
\makeatother

\setlist{wide, nosep, font=\rmfamily\normalfont}
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=\asbuk*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Текст
    \item Еще текст
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


